# The image cannot be selected from the Android 11 gallery

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to select an image from the gallery, but I can't get the file, I don't know why this is happening. Of course, I used the library I wrote, but it doesn't work for Android 11 and above. That's why I wrote again to access the gallery, which does not select. My goal is to access the camera and gallery that receives image files to work on Android 11 up and down.

my code:
https://github.com/oktayAmin/Imageutils/blob/main/imageUtils.java

Answer (score 0):

```
Add these query in manifest file...

  <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE" />
        </intent>
        <!-- Gallery -->
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT" />
            <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
        </intent>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK" />
            <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
        </intent>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.CHOOSER" />
        </intent>
    </queries>
```

Answer (score -1):

Flutter Solution

If you're facing issues with accessing images from the gallery, particularly on Android 11 and above due to changes in storage permissions and scoped storage, you need to ensure that your app requests the appropriate permissions and handles file access correctly.

Here's how you can modify the previous example to handle image picking on Android 11 and above:

1. **Add Permissions**: Ensure that your `AndroidManifest.xml` file requests the necessary permissions to access external storage. You may need to add the following permissions:

`xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

2. **Request Permissions**: Use the `permission_handler` package to request permissions at runtime. Add the package to your `pubspec.yaml`:

`yaml

```
dependencies:
  permission_handler: ^12.1.0
```

3. **Handle Scoped Storage**: Since Android 11 introduced scoped storage, you need to adapt your code to handle file access differently. The `image_picker` package should handle this internally, but if you're facing issues, you might need to check if the package is updated to handle scoped storage properly.

Here's the modified code with permissions handling using the `permission_handler` package:

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: ImagePickerPage(),
    );
  }
}

class ImagePickerPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ImagePickerPageState createState() => _ImagePickerPageState();
}

class _ImagePickerPageState extends State<ImagePickerPage> {
  XFile? _image;

  Future<void> _pickImage() async {
    final status = await Permission.photos.request();
    if (status.isGranted) {
      final picker = ImagePicker();
      final pickedImage = await picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
      setState(() {
        _image = pickedImage;
      });
    } else {
      showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
          title: Text('Permission Error'),
          content: Text('Please grant permission to access photos.'),
          actions: [
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
              child: Text('OK'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Image Picker Example'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: _image == null
            ? Text('No image selected.')
            : Image.file(
                File(_image!.path),
                width: 300,
                height: 300,
              ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _pickImage,
        tooltip: 'Pick Image',
        child: Icon(Icons.photo_library),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

In this modified version:

- We added the `permission_handler` package to request the necessary permissions at runtime.
- The `_pickImage` method now requests the `photos` permission before attempting to pick an image.
- If the permission is not granted, it displays an alert dialog informing the user and prompting them to grant the permission.

Make sure to test the app on Android 11 and above devices to ensure proper functionality. Additionally, keep an eye on updates to the `image_picker` package for improvements related to scoped storage handling.

Comment: this project was developed by Java and this isn't Flutter code'